# We should [finish] this

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

We have way too many tags about finish, and not an excerpt to be found

- [finish](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finish) - 44 questions
- [finishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing) - 127 questions
- [wood-finish](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-finish) - 18 questions
- [wood-finishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-finishing) - 56 questions

And then we have

- [refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refinishing) - 8 questions
- [basement-refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basement-refinishing) - 110 questions
- [hardwood-refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardwood-refinishing) - 95 questions

There seems to be a decent overlap here. I would suggest we merge/synonym as follows

- [finish](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finish) -> [finishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing)
- [wood-finish](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-finish) -> [wood-finishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-finishing) (unless there is a preference for both being [wood](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood) + [finishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing))
- [basement-refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basement-refinishing) -> [basement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basement) (1k+ questions)
- [refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refinishing) -> [finishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing)
- [hardwood-refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardwood-refinishing) -> [finishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing)

Comment: If the wood-finishing is kept then maybe hardwood-refinishing should merge to wood-finishing.